# How is this statement a proof?

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading this theorem and "proof" from [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/book/Apostol/ch1.pdf). The problem with this proof is, it does not elaborate the reasoning:[image]

and proof is:

[image]

How this gives the proof of this theorem from the second side?

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion, it doesn't. I think it requires some justification.